What is this usage of とした here?

会議室の空気がそれで切り替わった。重苦しいものから、次を考えられるさっぱりとしたものへ。

This is narration and the narrator is saying that room atmosphere change, from something heavy and stiff to something where you're able to think of what to say/do next.
What I'm stumbled is, what さっぱりとした here actually even doing? Wouldn't it work without it?

Related: Meaning of (と)した in やんわりとした暖房

「とした」is basically making さっぱり work as an adjective to describe もの. 「さっぱりとした空気」 would be a fresh atmosphere, or one of relief. This principle can apply to many onomatopoeia:

ぼんやりとした意識 (hazy consciousness)
どんよりとした曇り空 (dark, cloudy sky)
ちゃんとした理由 (a proper reason)「ちゃんとした」is lexicalized and has an entry in jisho

Why? I could point to a few things.

Onomatopoeia can easily take と
Many onomatopoeia can form verbs with する, for example びっくりする、ぼーっとする、しっかりする
「た」before a noun can express a state rather than a past action.

